# Regex for date format yyyy-mm-dd not working

Tags: jquery, regex, date

I have a date field .I need to check if date is of valid format.I use the following regex.But it is giving me result null.

```
alert(($('.from_date').val().trim()).match('/^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/'));
```

For example when I alerted the `$('.from_date').val()` ,its `'2015-11-04'`.But the above alert is giving me null.

Comment: don't use quotes, in `match(/^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/)`

Comment: why is this downvoted? are you discouraging people from learning?

Comment: @DanielCheung Upvote to counter the downvoters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes around the regex.

```js
document.write('2015-11-04'.match(/^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/));
```